# Debugging/logging ArcPy / Python code behind ArcMap function?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcpy

Considering I Can use the right click --> set datasource  at an  mxd file to change the datasource.

The following pictures describes how this can be done in arcmap.[image].
How can I see the arcpy / python code behind that process? Is there any sort of logging or debuging of what arcmap is doing on the back ? I suppose it calls the same arcpy functions as sb would call to perform the same result?

Question 2// COuld I see in some way the code behind "Set Datasource Tool" of arcmap.? If I will do this I will have my problem resolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set Data source Tool you run in ArcGIS Desktop is not available directly as a GP tool. The exact logic behind it is not exposed to the end user.

You can do that what this tool does in arcpy (with more advanced options): [Updating and fixing data sources with arcpy.mapping (arcpy.mapping)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s30000004p000000). The arcpy function that is the closest in terms of functionality is `findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths` ([link](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/MapDocument/00s30000000n000000/)).

Comment: I have already checked that. To be honest I have an other post related to the funtions That I cannot make work. Could you kindly check this if you have any experience with them ? Here is the post: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/146454/hot-to-change-datasource-using-arcpy